# Cartesian (cross) products and np.unique()

Tags: python, awkward-array

Depending on your few on my approach this is either a question about using `np.unique()` on `awkward1` arrays or a call for a better approach:

Let `a` and `b` be two `awkward1` arrays of the same outer length (number of events) but different inner lengths. For example:

`a = [[1, 2], [3]   , [] , [4, 5, 6]]`

`b = [[7]   , [3, 5], [6], [8, 9]]`

Let `f: (x, y) -> z` be a function that acts on two numbers `x` and `y` and results in the number `z`. For example:

`f(x, y):= y - x`

The idea is to compare every element in `a` with every element in `b` via `f` for each event and filter out the matches of `a` and `b` pairs that survive some cut applied to `f`. For example:

`f(x, y) < 4`

My approach for this is:

```
a = ak.from_iter(a)
b = ak.from_iter(b)

c = ak.cartesian({'x':a, 'y':b})
#c= [[{'x': 1, 'y': 7}, {'x': 2, 'y': 7}], [{'x': 3, 'y': 3}, {'x': 3, 'y': 5}], [], [{'x': 4, 'y': 8}, {'x': 4, 'y': 9}, {'x': 5, 'y': 8}, {'x': 5, 'y': 9}, {'x': 6, 'y': 8}, {'x': 6, 'y': 9}]]

i = ak.argcartesian({'x':a, 'y':b})
#i= [[{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}], [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 0, 'y': 1}], [], [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 0, 'y': 1}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 1, 'y': 1}, {'x': 2, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 1}]]

diff = c['y'] - c['x']
#diff= [[6, 5], [0, 2], [], [4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3]]

cut = diff < 4
#cut= [[False, False], [True, True], [], [False, False, True, False, True, True]]

new = c[cut]
#new= [[], [{'x': 3, 'y': 3}, {'x': 3, 'y': 5}], [], [{'x': 5, 'y': 8}, {'x': 6, 'y': 8}, {'x': 6, 'y': 9}]]

new_i = i[cut]
#new_i= [[], [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 0, 'y': 1}], [], [{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 1}]]
```

It is possible that pairs with the same element from `a` but different elements from `b` survive the cut. (e.g. `{'x': 3, 'y': 3}` and `{'x': 3, 'y': 5}`)

My goal is to group those pairs with the same element from `a` together and therefore reshape the `new` array into:

`new = [[], [{'x': 3, 'y': [3, 5]}], [], [{'x': 5, 'y': 8}, {'x': 6, 'y': [8, 9]}]]`

My only idea how to achieve this is to create a list of the indexes from `a` that are still present after the cut by using `new_i`:

```
i = new_i['x']
#i= [[], [0, 0], [], [1, 2, 2]]
```

However, I need a unique version of this list to make every index appear only once. This could be achieved with `np.unique()` in NumPy. But doesn't work in `awkward1`:

```
np.unique(i)

<__array_function__ internals> in unique(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: no implementation found for 'numpy.unique' on types that implement __array_function__: [<class 'awkward1.highlevel.Array'>]
```

My question:

Is their a `np.unique()` equivalent in `awkward1` and/or would you recommend a different approach to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I still don't know how to use `np.unique()` on my arrays, but I found a solution for my own problem:

In my previous approach I used the following code to pair up booth arrays.

```python
c = ak.cartesian({'x':a, 'y':b})
#c= [[{'x': 1, 'y': 7}, {'x': 2, 'y': 7}], [{'x': 3, 'y': 3}, {'x': 3, 'y': 5}], [], [{'x': 4, 'y': 8}, {'x': 4, 'y': 9}, {'x': 5, 'y': 8}, {'x': 5, 'y': 9}, {'x': 6, 'y': 8}, {'x': 6, 'y': 9}]]
```

However, with the `nested = True` parameter from `ak.cartesian()` I get a list grouped by the elements of `a`:

```python
c = ak.cartesian({'x':a, 'y':b}, axis = 1, nested = True)
#c= [[[{'x': 1, 'y': 7}], [{'x': 2, 'y': 7}]], [[{'x': 3, 'y': 3}, {'x': 3, 'y': 5}]], [], [[{'x': 4, 'y': 8}, {'x': 4, 'y': 9}], [{'x': 5, 'y': 8}, {'x': 5, 'y': 9}], [{'x': 6, 'y': 8}, {'x': 6, 'y': 9}]]]
```

After the cut I end up with:

```python
new = c[cut]
#new= [[[], []], [[{'x': 3, 'y': 3}, {'x': 3, 'y': 5}]], [], [[], [{'x': 5, 'y': 8}], [{'x': 6, 'y': 8}, {'x': 6, 'y': 9}]]]
```

I extract the `y` values and reduce the most inner layer of the nested lists of `new` to only one element:

```python
y = new['y']
#y= [[[], []], [[3, 5]], [], [[], [8], [8, 9]]]

new = ak.firsts(new, axis = 2)
#new= [[None, None], [{'x': 3, 'y': 3}], [], [None, {'x': 5, 'y': 8}, {'x': 6, 'y': 8}]]
```

(I tried to use `ak.firsts()` with `axis = -1` but it seems to be not implemented yet.)

---

Now every most inner entry in `new` belongs to exactly one element from `a`. By replacing the current `y` of `new` with the previously extracted `y` I end up with my desired result:

```python
new['y'] = y
#new= [[None, None], [{'x': 3, 'y': [3, 5]}], [], [None, {'x': 5, 'y': [8]}, {'x': 6, 'y': [8, 9]}]]
```

---

Anyway, should you know a better solution, I'd be pleased to hear it.